# Introductory text book for a post-graduate level econometrics course

Tags: textbooks

I am currently applying for a post-graduate course in Economics, having completed my undergraduate degree in physics. The course contains an econometrics module, and I am looking for some recommendations for some appropriate textbooks. Given my undergraduate study, I think it can be assumed that I can at least handle the level of maths required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good graduate level econometrics books are:

Verbeek: A Guide to Modern Econometrics
Pesaran: Time Series and Panel Data Econometrics
Hamilton: Time Series Analysis (only covers time series)

If you are planning to do PhD in policy economics then this one is an important read:

Angrist and Pischke: Mostly Harmless Econometrics

Comment: How does Woolbridge and Hayashi compare to these? Can you please point out the difference between Woodbridge, Hayashi and Angrist? I do understand that Woodbridge is the most introductory among the three.

Comment: @solowsupremacy I don't know Hayashi. Wooldridge's book is good but its on undergraduate level OP requested graduate level books. Wooldridge is not focusing on policy analysis so there is little overlap with Angrist et al, Wooldridge covers most of what is in the other 3 books I mentioned but on undergraduate level

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks.

Comment: Greene's Econometric Analysis is good. Also Bruce Hansen's notes are incredible.